# Nav bar is resizing when I try to begin adding content to rest of page

Tags: html, css, flexbox, navbar, nav

I am brand new to learning HTML and CSS and am working on a practice page.
Also this is my first question on here so apologies if I have made a mistake formatting anywhere.

I have tried to make a simple nav bar with a drop down feature on one of the links. When I try to then start adding content to the page after , anything I add starts to resize the navbar itself.

So for example if I add an H1 tag and type text underneath the navbar section, the nav bar stretches further down the page.

What can I do to keep the nav bar as it is so I can begin adding content without it changing please?

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Portfolio Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <navbar>
        <ul class="nav-list">
            <li class="nav-item">
                Logo</li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
                    <ul class="nav-item-drop">
                        <li><a href="#">Project 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Project 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Project 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <button class="button-primary">Contact</button></li>
    </navbar>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Alfa+Slab+One&display=swap');

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background-color: rgb(164, 164, 164);
}


.nav-list {
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px;
    font-family: "Alfa Slab One", sans-serif;
    padding: 10px 0px;
    margin: 10px 0px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
}

.nav-item {
    list-style: none;
    padding-right: 3rem;

}

.nav-item:hover ul, .nav-item:focus ul {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}

.nav-item-drop {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgba(234, 211, 78, 0.6);
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 2.5rem 1rem 1rem 1rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    list-style: none;
    gap: 1rem;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition:opacity 200ms ease-in-out;
}



.nav-item a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgba(234, 211, 78, 0.6);
}

.nav-item a:hover {
    color:white;
}

.nav-item:first-child {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: 20px;
    font-size: 2rem;
    color: rgba(234, 211, 78, 0.6);
}

.button-primary {
    font-family: "Alfa Slab One", sans-serif;
    padding: .3rem .6rem;
    background-color: rgba(234, 211, 78, 0.6);
    color: black;
}

.button-primary:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: black;
    background-color: rgba(253, 199, 3, 0.95);
    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to close the `<ul class="nav-list">` tag.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Alfa+Slab+One&display=swap');

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background-color: rgb(164, 164, 164);
}


.nav-list {
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px;
    font-family: "Alfa Slab One", sans-serif;
    padding: 10px 0px;
    margin: 10px 0px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
}

.nav-item {
    list-style: none;
    padding-right: 3rem;

}
h1
{
  background-color:red;
}
.nav-item:hover ul, .nav-item:focus ul {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}

.nav-item-drop {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgba(234, 211, 78, 0.6);
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 2.5rem 1rem 1rem 1rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    list-style: none;
    gap: 1rem;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition:opacity 200ms ease-in-out;
}



.nav-item a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgba(234, 211, 78, 0.6);
}

.nav-item a:hover {
    color:white;
}

.nav-item:first-child {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: 20px;
    font-size: 2rem;
    color: rgba(234, 211, 78, 0.6);
}

.button-primary {
    font-family: "Alfa Slab One", sans-serif;
    padding: .3rem .6rem;
    background-color: rgba(234, 211, 78, 0.6);
    color: black;
}

.button-primary:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: black;
    background-color: rgba(253, 199, 3, 0.95);
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Portfolio Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <navbar>
        <ul class="nav-list">
            <li class="nav-item">
                Logo</li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
                    <ul class="nav-item-drop">
                        <li><a href="#">Project 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Project 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Project 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <button class="button-primary">Contact</button></li>
        </ul>
    </navbar>
      <h1>test</h1>
      <h1>test</h1>
      <h1>test</h1>
      <h1>test</h1>
</body>
</html>
```